# Left Outer Join and simple join within 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I am new to queries so excuse my ignorance.

The temp table #all has three columns: cod, cust_name, end_date. This table has 2500 rows. When the below query is run, I am not getting all the codes but it gives me about 400 rows.

For the HCS_Dtl and HCIS_Hd table: there will always be one matching row in both

```
    SELECT p.cod, count(d.FormNo), SUM(d.NetAmt) 
    FROM #all p left outer join HCS_Dtl d on p.cod=d.Code
        join HCIS_Hd h on d.FormNo=h.FormNo
    WHERE 
    h.TimeStmp between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-28 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY p.cod
```

I need that I get those 2500 rows from #all even they don't have a form during this time period that I am mentioning in where clause of the query. How could it be possible?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: if you want full rows in #all then remove where condition and then join means it acts as inner join 'join HCIS_Hd h on d.FormNo=h.FormNo' make it as left join

Comment: @mohan111 I am sorry I didn't get your point. Do you mean I change like this?

        SELECT p.cod, count(d.FormNo), SUM(d.NetAmt) 
            FROM #all p left outer join HCS_Dtl d on p.cod=d.Code
                left join HCIS_Hd h on d.FormNo=h.FormNo and h.TimeStmp between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-28 23:59:59'
            GROUP BY p.cod

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LEFT JOIN` on table `HCIS_Hd`

```
 SELECT p.cod, count(d.FormNo), SUM(d.NetAmt) 
FROM #all p left outer join HCS_Dtl d on p.cod=d.Code
    LEFT JOIN HCIS_Hd h on d.FormNo=h.FormNo
WHERE 
h.TimeStmp between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY p.cod
```

Comment: This returns the same number of rows as the actual query in question